# simple string split is returning object instead array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying a simple string split in NodeJS, but it is returning an object, not array.

```
var mytext = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k";
var arr = mytext.split(",");
console.log(typeof mytext); <======= output string
console.log(typeof arr);    <======= output object
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4NnQ/

why?

Comment: in js `array` is an `object`

Comment: I've been amazed on this.. I have a string, splitting using \r\n, and somehow it becomes an object.

I'm using the clipboard onpaste to grab the string, but definitely can't understand what it's doing.. When I use control.log, it appears as an array..

Even tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(s)) to switch, but still an object.

All I can say is use push() and pop() to work with it.. Hopefully I can figure this one out....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The output of [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is an Array and that is an Object.

```
console.log(typeof []);
// object
```

You can confirm that the returned object is an array, like this

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arr));
// [object Array]
console.log(arr);
// [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k' ]
```

Quoting from the MDN Documentation of [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Summary),

> The **split()** method splits a String object into an **array of strings** by separating the string into substrings.

Comment: I did this, but `console.log(typeof arr)` gives "string" not "array", did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are objects in javascript.

If you want to check if its an array -

you can do -

`Array.isArray(arr)`

Answer (score 1):

Split method always returns an array . Array is an object in javascript. If you want to check whether it is an array use Array.isArray(arr)

Answer (score 0):

An array is an object.

[Read about `typeof` results here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Ftypeof#Description)

Answer (score 0):

If you output as

```
console.log(arr);
```

You will see an array

Answer (score 0):

```
var mytext = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k";
var arr = mytext.split(",");
console.log(typeof mytext); <======= output string
console.log(arr);    `this will return object`
for(i=0;i<=10; i++){
console.log(arr[i]);    
}
```